# name this property: $‖Ax‖=c‖x‖$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I was recently working with some matrices that had this property:
$$||Ax||_1=(n-1)||x||_1,\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
^n$$
where $n$ is number of columns in $A$. It was a useful feature for analysis. Is there existing research on this topic? Does it have a name? It doesn't have to be specific to the $L_1$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying this is true for all $n$-vectors $x$?  If so, $A$ is $n-1$ times an isometry (if $A$ is $n \times n$) or a partial isometry (if $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m > n$).

Comment: Yes -- true for all $x$.